# Run sqlite3 command line in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, sqlite, jenkins-pipeline

I want to operate database(sqlite3) with jenkins pipeline, but powershell plugin doesn't recognize sqlite3 command.

I have installed sqlite3 correctly on the slave "EPPDockerHost"(Win10), and `sqlite3` commands work well on the machine. I have tried powershell plugin and bat plugin on Jenkins pipeline, but neither work. The error information are same:

> 'sqlite3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Pipeline Code:

```
pipeline {
agent { node('EPPDockerHost')}

stages {
    stage('test') {
        steps {
            dir('C:\\Users\\Cydval\\Desktop\\Project1') {
                bat """
                    sqlite3
                """
            } } } } }
```

Execution log:

> [Project1] Running batch script
>
> C:\Users\Cydval\Desktop\Project1>sqlite3 'sqlite3' is not recognized
>   as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Hi Cydval, how is the code run on your node? If this would be a linux machine it would be run under specific user. Maybe this could be a valid point for further inspection - is there a jenkins specific user that maybe doesn't have access or sqlite3 installed at all?

Comment: Hi, the master and slaves of Jenkins are all Windows machine, (Win7 and Win10). Do you mean Jenkins user or operation system user? I have set the system environment variables on slave machine and I am sure all system users of slave machine can use sqlite3. However, I don't how to install sqlite for Jenkins user, and my jenkins account is administrator

Comment: Just execute this in your pipeline on windows slave: `echo %username%`, then log into this account the check if it's installed.